# Angular2 trying to slice string object using SlicePipe in template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

Ref : https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/SlicePipe-class.html. Trying to slice first 20 characters of a string object.

Tried :

```
<p>{{item.description | slice:0:20}}...</p>
```

and

```
<p>{{item.description}}[0:20]: '{{item.description | slice:0:20}}'</p>
```

Here item.description is of type String

```
export class Details {
  description: string; 
}

@Component({
  selector: 'editor'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  item: details = <Details>{};
}
```

Note : I am getting value for description in my template using `{{item.description}}` but when i slice it says

> Invalid argument 'undefined' for pipe 'SlicePipe'

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7152

It seems to have been fixed recently but not yet shipped.

Comment: Is there any other way to slice a string. I am trying to do paragraph Read more functionality(can be done on css) i am trying on angular2. Any info on stable release of Angular2.

Comment: You could just create your own slice pipe. The link above contains the source including the fix (it's just a few lines of cod). It's just not yet included in the shipped Angular versions.